# How can I display a table value based on the selection from a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, laravel, eloquent

I want to display (on an input text field) the description of a product (which is a MEDIUM TEXT field type) based on the selection of a dropdown containing the product ID. The tricky part is that I want to query my database by the product ID.

I'm able to display the product description on an input text field using Javascript but I want to query my database by the product ID.

I have a very simple database: product_ID | product_descrip
"product_descrip" is a MEDIUM TEXT field type and can contains up to 16Mb for each product.

My CONTROLLER:

```
public function findProduct() {
    $products = Product::All();

    return view("updatingStock", compact("products"));
  }

public function stockUpdate(Request $req) {

  $selectedProduct = Product::where("product_ID", "=", $req["productsOption1"])->first();

  $selectedProduct->update();

  return redirect("/updatingStock");
}
```

My VIEW:

```
<select class="form-control" name="productsOption1" id="dropdown1">
      <option value="" selected>Product...</option>
    @foreach ($products as $product)
      <option value={{$product["product_descrip"}}>{{$product["product_ID"]}}</option>;
    @endforeach
  </select>

<input class="form-control" id="myproduct" type="text" placeholder=""  readonly>
```

MY SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var oneproduct = document.getElementById('myproduct1');
            var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown1');

            mydropdown.onchange = function(){
                  myproduct.value = this.value;
            }
        </script>
```

As you can see, I'm able to display the product description on the input readonly field but I need to query my database by product_ID, not by product_descrip

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](https://jsfiddle.net/junaidir/nfgy2akz/6/)

Then change your select vlaue to id,
in js initiate array with your data like this

```
var Products = {!!json_encode($selectedProduct  -> toArray()) !!}
```

then then use the code in js fiddle

Comment: Thanks @Rao Would you mind being more explicit regarding if I need to ADD your code or REPLACE mine? How my VIEW; my CONTROLLER and my SCRIPT will look like with your suggestions? Thanks again. –

Comment: you dont need to change you controller or blade. In your JS code where you are listening for SELCET on change event add the if part there, i will update my answer

Comment: Thanks again @Rao but $selectedProduct is not shared with the view in my code. I still don't get how my ENTIRE JS script would look like. Please, write the whole JS script code, including all my declarations. I'm sorry, I'm pretty new with OOP & Laravel.

Comment: selected product is supposed to be you dropdown, remvoe that line, use this fucntion insde your onchange and send it your dropdown vlaue it

Comment: I'm really sorry @Rao but I can't get what you mean. I need you to review my code again and re-write the parts that I need to change. I tried to understand your directions and tested them with no success. In my code, $selectedProduct is the variable that contains all the products and it's the variable I use to loop through those products in my dropdown. Thanks again.

Comment: _But I need to query my database by product_ID, not by product_descrip_ where did you query this. where is the code..

Comment: In my controller

Comment: Thanks again @Rao but it still doesn't work. I tried your solution on JS Fiddle and when I select the product ID I get "undefined", instead of the product description.